# How to insert image using link from XML document in a HTML file?

Tags: html, xml

I've got a XML file and I am making a HTML file from the document.

I am grabbing information from the XML document at the moment using this

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("url")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

For text in the HTML document I am then doing something like this
    `<p id = "url"></p>`

What I do not know if is the text of "url" is the URL of an image, how do I insert this URL into an HTML image tag so I can insert an image into my page?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can check `nodeValue` whether it contains image extension *.png, .jpg, .gif* etc in it before adding to image tag:

[**DEMO:**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tf5LM/1/)

```
var nodeVal = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("url")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
if(nodeVal.indexOf('.png') > -1 || nodeVal.indexOf('.jpg') > -1 || nodeVal.indexOf('.gif') > -1){
    document.getElementById("yourImageTagId").src = nodeVal;
}
```